# Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation

Tags: android, api, android-studio, gradle

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of android studio (v 1.4). After creating a new project, I see this error about the gradle refresh failure:

> Error: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.4'.

I've tried so many different things that I have found online and no fix. When I open the layout window of the project it says "Gradle project sync failed..."

I am not sure what the error means at all and also do not know how to use any other different version of it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, fix is don't use gradle 2.4 I deleted gradle/gradle 2.4 folder and in gradle/wrapper/ gradle-wrapper-properties in build directory change 'distributionUrl' to another gradle distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting everything in `/Library/Java/Extensions/` fixed this for me.

Issue with more info: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1451

Comment: This helped me find the solution.  Starting studio from the commandline I noticed an error "SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]" - and when I searched my computer for slf4j I found two very old .jar files in /usr/java/packages/lib/ext/.  Removing them allowed me to build my project.

Comment: Glad it could help! :D

Comment: Where is that `/Library/` folder??

Answer (score 0):

Add lines at the end of eclipse.ini

```
--illegal-access=warn
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

[source](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1140)